# Unix returned phone number, need to format

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have data that is in the form like this

```
JSD4863 XXX-XX-XXXX DOE, JOHN C JR-II BISS CPSC BS   INFO TECH   412/779-9445
```

Its a large list so I made a loop to read in specific lines. It looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for linePosition in {11..22}
do
  holder=`sed -n "${linePosition}p" $1|awk '{print $12}'`
  echo "$holder"
done
```

It prints out the number `412/779-9445`. Works for all the lines
However, I am only interested in the last 4 numbers (eg `9445`)
What can i add in my loop to have it delimit to this?
I tried `cut`, maybe my syntax was just wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed -rn 's/.*-([0-9]{4})$/\1/p'`

Comment: this produced blank lines as well.

Comment: I put a bunch of lines in stuff.txt and ran the following: ```cat stuff.txt | sed -rn 's/.*-(.*)$/\1/p' | xargs echo```

Comment: You could also sub your whole code with this (reads only lines between 11 and 22): ```cat stuff.txt | sed -rn '11,22s/.*-(.*)$/\1/p' | xargs echo```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following. With the first command I am showing you what a working script could look like. With the second command I am showing you output from the example script.

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh
sed -n '11,22p' $1 | grep -o '[0-9]*$'

$ ./a.sh a.txt
9445
9445
9445
9445
9445
9445
9445
9445
9445
9445
9445
9445
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk only:

```
awk 'FNR>=11 && FNR<=22 {print $12}' file
```

sed + awk:

```
sed -n '11,22p' | awk '{print $12}'
```